# inflating class fragment が出てしまう｡

Tags: android, android-fragments

以下の様な`fragment`を2つ並べたようなViewを作ったのですが､Activityの`setContentView`で以下のエラーが出てしまいます｡

**activity_video_player.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika.VideoPlayerActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:name="com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika.VideoInfoFragment"
    android:id="@+id/video_info_fragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

**エラー:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika/com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika.VideoPlayerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
        at com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika.VideoPlayerActivity.onCreate(VideoPlayerActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
......
```

続けて､問題の起こった`fragment`と`activity`を示します｡

**VideoPlayerActivity:**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;


public class VideoPlayerActivity extends FragmentActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,
    VideoInfoFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{
private static final String VIDEO_ID = "videoId";
private String apiKey;
private YouTubePlayerSupportFragment player;
private String videoId;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);

    //videoIdを取得
    Intent data = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    videoId = extras !=null ? extras.getString(VIDEO_ID) : "";

    //プレイヤを読み込む
    player = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
    apiKey=DeveloperKey.API_KEY;
    //プレイヤーを初期化
    player.initialize(apiKey, this);

    VideoInfoFragment viFragment = (VideoInfoFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.video_info_fragment);
    viFragment.getVideoId(videoId);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    if(!b){
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_video_player, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){

}
}
```

**VideoInfoFragment:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class VideoInfoFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private RequestQueue mQueue;
private String videoId;
private VideoDetail videoDetail;
private VideoItems videoItem;
private ChannelSearchResult chSearch;
private ChannelSearchItems chItem;
private VideoDetail suggestVideoDetail;
private List<VideoItems> suggestVideoList1;
private List<VideoItems> suggestVideoList2;
private VideoSearchResult suggestVideoSearchResult;
private String apiKey;
private ListView mListView;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment VideoInfoFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static VideoInfoFragment newInstance() {
    VideoInfoFragment fragment = new VideoInfoFragment();
    return fragment;
}

public VideoInfoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mQueue = RequestSingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
    apiKey = DeveloperKey.API_KEY;
    suggestVideoList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    suggestVideoList2 = new ArrayList<>();

    //再生動画の動画情報をリクエスト
    String videoRequestUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,statistics&id="
            + videoId + "&key=" + apiKey;
    videoRequest(videoRequestUrl);

    //再生動画のチャンネル情報をリクエスト
    String channelRequestUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id,snippet,statistics&id="
            + videoItem.snippet.channelId + "&key=" + apiKey;
    channelRequest(channelRequestUrl);

    //おすすめ動画の検索ワード(Tagを追加する)
    String searchWord = videoItem.snippet.tags.get(0);
    for(int i=1; i<videoItem.snippet.tags.size(); i++){
        searchWord += " | " + videoItem.snippet.tags.get(i);
    }

    //おすすめ動画を検索
    String suggestVideosListRequestUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id" +
            "&q=" + searchWord + "&maxResults=20" + "&type=video&videoDefinition=high&key=" + apiKey;
    suggestVideosListRequest(suggestVideosListRequestUrl);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle saveInstanceState){
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video_info, container, false);
    this.mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.video_info_list);
    InfoListAdapter adapter = new InfoListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            videoItem, chItem, suggestVideoList1);
    this.mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}

//動画情報をリクエスト
private void videoRequest(String url){
    RequestSingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(new JsonObjectRequest(JsonRequest.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").create();

            videoDetail = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), VideoDetail.class);
            videoItem = videoDetail.items.get(0);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }));
}

//チャンネル情報をリクエスト
private void channelRequest(String url){
    RequestSingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(new JsonObjectRequest(JsonRequest.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").create();

            chSearch = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), ChannelSearchResult.class);
            chItem = chSearch.items.get(0);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }));
}

//おすすめ動画を20個検索
private void suggestVideosListRequest(String url){
    RequestSingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(new JsonObjectRequest(JsonRequest.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").create();

            suggestVideoSearchResult = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), VideoSearchResult.class);

            String suggestVideoIds = suggestVideoSearchResult.items.get(0).id.videoId;
            for(int i=1; i<suggestVideoSearchResult.items.size(); i++){
                suggestVideoIds += "," + suggestVideoSearchResult.items.get(i).id.videoId;
            }

            String suggestVideosSearchUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?" +
                    "part=id,snippet,contentDetails,statistics&id=" + suggestVideoIds +
                    "&key=" + apiKey;
            suggestVideosRequest(suggestVideosSearchUrl);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }));
}

//おすすめ動画の動画情報をリクエスト
private void suggestVideosRequest(String url){
    RequestSingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(new JsonObjectRequest(JsonRequest.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").create();

            suggestVideoDetail = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), VideoDetail.class);
            for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
                if(!suggestVideoDetail.items.isEmpty()) {
                    suggestVideoList1.add(suggestVideoDetail.items.get(i));
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(int i=9; i<20; i++){
                if(!suggestVideoDetail.items.isEmpty()) {
                    suggestVideoList2.add(suggestVideoDetail.items.get(i));
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }));
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    if(mQueue!=null){
        mQueue.stop();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    if(mQueue!=null){
        mQueue.start();
    }
}


// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

/*ここからオリジナルのコードです｡*/
public void getVideoId(String videoId){
    this.videoId=videoId;
}
```

}

ちなみに､この`VideoInfoFragment`を追加する以前はエラーは出ませんでした｡
あと関係があるのかわからないのですが､`AndroidManifest`で`NoActionBar`を指定しています｡
このエラーについて､検索し､様々な方法を試しましたが結局､直りませんでした｡
どなたか解決方法がわかる方､教えて頂ければ幸いです｡
よろしくお願いします｡

Comment: `LinearLayout`の終了タグはあるのでしょうか？

Comment: すみません｡書き損じていました｡修正します｡

Comment: 書き損じていたのはスタックオーバーフロー内のことで、実際のコードには書かれていました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました｡

`Fragment`を静的に設置した場合､`onCreate`､`onCreateView`内では､まだ親のActivityが生成されていないので､`getActivity()`を呼ぶことができませんでした｡ なので､`onCreateView`で呼ぶ必要がある場合は､`Fragment`を動的に生成する必要があるようでした｡